# Grant on dynamic database name in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to grant a new user permissions on the current database (whose name I do not know).

Basically I want to archive something like this:

```
grant all privileges on database $(SELECT current_database();) to my_new_user;
```

Any hints how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot combine `GRANT`s with queries directly, but you may write a small block to achieve that. Since `GRANT` allows only database names and no variables, you have to create the command as string and execute it with `EXECUTE`:

```
DO $_$
    DECLARE
        the_database TEXT := CURRENT_DATABASE();
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE FORMAT('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE %s TO my_new_user', the_database);
    END
$_$;
```

**Addendum**: If the database name might contain special characters like dashes you should put the name into double quotes:

```
DO $_$
    DECLARE
        the_database TEXT := CURRENT_DATABASE();
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE FORMAT('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE %I TO my_new_user', the_database);
    END
$_$;
```

Comment: Just a FYI for anyone who might find this later: I had to add `""` around the `%s` since my DB name had a dash in it.

Comment: @stiller_leser: Thanks for the hint. I've included that into my post.

Comment: you don't need to wrap in quotes, simply use `%I` instead of `%s`, which will automatically include quotes if it's necessary.

Comment: @pyramation Unfortunately, I saw your post only now. I have adjusted the code accordingly. Thank you for the hint. :)